# Visual Basic - variable names auto increment / loop

Tags: vba, variables

Is there a way when I want to do this:

```
textbox1.text = x + i  
textbox2.text = x + i  
textbox3.text = x + i
```

To do for example like this?

```
for l = 0 to 2   
  textbox(l) = x + i  
next
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please don't use the answer section to ask a follow-up question.  Either edit your question or add a comment to my answer.  I'm glad my answer worked for your original question.  I haven't used the PictureBox control, so not sure what the issue is.  One thing I notice is you've got an extra "m" in `ImagemPictureBox`, I think.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be `ImagePictureBox.Picture`.

Comment: and yes i have an "m" in that because that's a variable and because im portuguese so -> Imagem = Image xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming these controls are inside a userform, do something like:

```
Private Sub FillTextboxes()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long

    x = 10
    For i = 0 To 2
        Me.Controls("textbox" & i + 1).Text = x + i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `Long`s? That seems... excessive. (And you don't have to declare `i` in advance, either.)

Comment: @minitech According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754%28v=office.10%29.aspx): "VBA converts all integer values to type Long, even if they are declared as type Integer. Therefore, there is no longer a performance advantage to using Integer variables; in fact, Long variables might be slightly faster because VBA does not have to convert them."  Not sure what you mean by "declare in advance," unless you think this is .Net.  And why are you indenting my code.  That seems ... fussy.

Comment: what does 2 mean in `for i = 0 To 2`

Comment: @NimitzE , the same thing it usually means:an integer between 1 and 3. Care to elaborate?

Comment: assumming that I have 5 textboxes, should i replace 2 with 5? sorry for this confusion...

Comment: @NimitzE., no problem.  In that case you'd use 0 to 4. Although actually, I was trying to stick close to the code in the original question. Starting from scratch I'd use 1 to 5. Then you could get rid of the `+1` part.

Comment: I remove the +1 part already, thats why I should use 1 to 5. Hehehe thanks, I am close on figuring out a solution to my problem.

Comment: @NimitzE., I'm glad to hear it.